# WordPress main menu doesnt navigate back to main page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using WordPress with Jupiter theme.

I am having an issue I have a main menu setup where I scroll to different parts of the web page using `#` and sectionIDs, e.g. `myurl/#home` or `myurl/#contact`.

Now I want to add another menu item where I will be directed to a different page, e.g. `myurl/newpage`. However once I reach this page from main page I cannot use the menu again. The navigation menu buttons try to add `#home` to `myurl/newpage/#home`.

I want to know how can I navigate to another page on my site without breaking the main navigation menu or how to navigate back flawlessly from my menu.

Comment: `websitedomain/#home websitedomain/#contact websitedomain/newpage`

Comment: Please post a link to your site

Comment: http://it-profiler.com/submit/ is the page where the navigation menu stops working. if you go simply to it-profiler.com the menu works fine

Comment: You should put your website url infront

`http://it-profiler.com//#home

http://it-profiler.com//#contact

http://it-profiler.com//submit`

Comment: i tried doing that already it makes the menu work but it makes the menu tabs always apear underlined for some reason. For e.g right now i have the entire url istead of just a #home in the menu and the home appears to be underlined. Is there a way i can create a second menu and associate it with the subpage it-profiler.com/submit

Comment: u will need to adjust ur css, when the menu is underlined

Comment: I am very new to wordpress and php can you tell me how to do it so the menu is no longer underlined?

Comment: is the home that stays underline right?

Comment: yes since thats the only one on which i have used the entire link for now but before posting here i made the entire menu with full links and every time i put the full link instead of just #home , #contact etc those menu items appear underlined